# Change ViewController when device orientation changes?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to figure out how to switch VCs when the orientation changes. I have 2 different ones, portraitVC and landscapeVC, in the same storyboard. The goal is to have essentially the same thing happen in landscape, but with a different UIImage. Anyone have some help?

The logic should be something like:

```
if orientation is landscape {
    use landscapeVC 
} else {
    Use portraitVC
}
```

Comment: Only post code that illustrates the issue!

Comment: @meaning-matters the whole code is the issue. I don't know what to fix lol

Comment: Really, including each and every image initialization, the sloppy empty lines, and commented out code?

Comment: @meaning-matters If I am having issues with the program as a whole, yes, I do believe that the whole code needs to be posted. I understand where you are coming from, but for my brain to be able to comprehend what is being taught to me here I would like for the responders to see everything that I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not quite sure of exactly what you're trying to achieve but here are two possible solutions:

#### 1. Change the UIImageView image on rotation

You can add an observer to be notified when the device changes orientation.

Add this to your viewDidLoad():

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didRotate), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

The following function will be called when the orientation changes:

```
func didRotate(notification: NSNotification) {
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
        // Change UIImageView image here
    }

    if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
        // Change UIImageView image here
    }
}
```

You can change the image for portrait or landscape orientations with this code. Oh! And don't forget to remove the observer in your viewWillDisappear():

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

#### 2. Change the layout and UI on rotation

This is a little bit more tricky, but not difficult at all. You'll need to work with the Storyboard Size Classes.

[image: Compact x Regular Size Class]

Checkout the bottom-middle part of the image above. See where it says **wCompact hRegular**, that means your designing for all iPhones in portrait. For iPhones in landscape, use **wAny hCompact**. See how some of the constraints in the image above are disabled? That's because they are not in effect for the specific size class.

[image: Any x Compact Size Class]

By using Size Classes, you can customize your UI for not only Portrait and Landscape, but also for more specific devices (iPhones and iPads). You can read a bit more about this topic [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html).

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow. Using size classes was the perfect solution. I spent hours trying to figure out the code to do exactly what size classes do. Thank you so very much for your solution.